# Prove that $\int s\ d\mu \leq \int f\ d\mu.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-writing

> Let $(X, \mathcal S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\Bbb L_0^+$ and $\Bbb L^+$ respectively denote the collection of all non-negative simple $\mathcal S$-measurable functions and the collection of all non-negative $\mathcal S$-measurable functions. Let $f \in \Bbb L^+$ and $s \in \Bbb L_0^+$ be such that $0 \leq s \leq f.$ Then $\int s\ d\mu \leq \int f\ d\mu.$

The proof of the above theorem has been given by Inder K. Rana in his lecture serirs on *Measure and Integration* which can also be found in his book *An Introduction to Measure and Integration* which argues along the following lines.

> Since $f \in \Bbb L^+$ there exists a sequence $\{s_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\Bbb L_0^+$ such that $s_n\ \big\uparrow\ f$ as $n \to \infty.$ So $$\int f\ d\mu = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int s_n\ d\mu.$$ Consider the sets $$B_n : = \left \{x \in X\ \big |\ s(x) \leq s_n(x) \right \},\ \forall\ n \geq 1.$$
> Then $B_n \in \mathcal S,\ \forall\ n \geq 1$ and $B_n \subseteq B_{n+1}$ with $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = X.$ Let $\nu : \mathcal S \longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ be defined by $$\nu (E) : = \int s\ \chi_E\ d\mu = \int_E s\ d\mu,\ E \in \mathcal S.$$ Then it is easy to see that $\nu$ is a measure on $\mathcal S.$ Since $B_n\ \big\uparrow\ X,$ we have \begin{align*} \int s\ d\mu  = \nu(X) & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \nu(B_n) \\ & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{B_n} s\ d\mu \\ & \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_n} s_n\ d\mu \\ & \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int s_n\ d\mu \\ & = \int f\ d\mu. \end{align*}

In this proof I don't understand why $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = X.$ Since $s \leq f$ there might exist some $x \in X$ such that $s(x) = f(x)$ in which case $s_n (x) \lt s(x)$ for all $n \geq 1$ if $f \in \Bbb L^+ \setminus \Bbb L_0^+.$ To overcome this draw back what I did is as follows $:$

Let us fix $\varepsilon \gt 0$ arbitrarily. Let us define $$B_n : = \left \{x \in X\ \big |\ s(x) < s_n(x) + \varepsilon \right \},\ \forall\ n \geq 1.$$ Then also $B_n \in \mathcal S,\ \forall\ n \geq 1.$ In this case it is clear that $B_n\ \big\uparrow\ X.$ So we have by the previous argument \begin{align*} \int s\ d\mu  = \nu(X) & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \nu(B_n) \\ & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{B_n} s\ d\mu \\ & \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_n} (s_n + \varepsilon)\ d\mu \\ & \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int (s_n + \varepsilon)\ d\mu \\ & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left ( \int s_n\ d\mu \right ) + \varepsilon \int d\mu \\ & = \int f\ d\mu + \varepsilon. \mu(X).  \end{align*} So if $\mu (X) \lt +\infty$ then letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ we have the required result. But what will happen if $\mu (X) = +\infty$? Any suggestion in improving this proof will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time for reading.

**Source** $:$ https://youtu.be/4UIiG8yUBv8?list=PLtKWB-wrvn4mbGE2XeUbnVw1cwAj4-f0C&t=964

**EDIT** $:$ My proof perfectly makes sense as this little note on the **Arithmetic in** $[0,\infty]$ suggested in the book *Real and Complex Analysis* by Walter Rudin. Here's what has been given at Page no. $18$ $:$

[image]

Comment: There are mistakes in the proof. It is not true that $\cup_n B_n =X$. The case $\mu (X)=\infty$ also causes problems.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir can you please check the video link what I have just added?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir can such errors be acceptable from a professor of IIT Bombay? Why should we (the students) be blamed always for mistakes?

Comment: Mistakes in the book have been pointed out earlier also on this site .Beyond that wouldn't lie to comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir how to get rid of such draw backs? Can you please provide me a correct version of the proof?

Comment: My personal recommendation is to follow Rudin's book.

Comment: Do you mean the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin @KaviRamaMurthy sir?

Comment: Yes, that is the book I was referring to. But at a later stage you could also look at Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir modified proof perfectly makes sense as suggested in the book *Real and Complex Analysis* by Rudin. There's nothing ambiguous in it as far as I think. Look at my edit section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109564/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Answer (score 1):

I think when proving something as trivial and fundamental, it is important to know what you can start with. That is, what kind of theorem you are allowed to use.

That said, I think my approach will be to consider $f-s\geq0$ and there exists a simple process $g_n $ such that the limit of $g_n$ tends to $f-s$, the proof that $\int{(f-s)}d \mu \geq 0$ follows trivially.